# Directional Derivatives of a function existence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, limits, derivatives

let $f(x,y)=\frac {xy} {x^2+y^2}$ when $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$ and f(x,y)=0 when $(x,y) = (0,0)$.

Find all vectors $u \ne 0$ where directional vector at (0,0) in the direction of u exists and evaluate it. Is it differentiable and continuous at 0?

here is what i did:

\begin{align}
\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(\mathbf{a} + h\mathbf{y}) - f(\mathbf{a})}{h}
&= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f((0,0) + h(y_{1},y_{2})) - f(\mathbf{0})}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(hy_{1},hy_{2})}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{(hy_1) (hy_2)}{h((hy_1)^2 + (hy_2)^2)} \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{(y_1) (y_2)}{((hy_1) + (hy_2))}
\end{align}

how would i evalute this limit? in addition, how would i show it is differentiable or not? i know that i just have to find two relations between x and y that do not yield the same limit to prove it is not differetiable, but how would i prove if it is differentiable?

Comment: It is not continuous at zero. Consider for example taking the limit in the direction of the lines $y=2x$ and $y=3x$ and you can see that the two limits are different. It is thus also non differentiable at zero.

Comment: got it but how do i evluate the limit for directional derivative that i showed above? it seems like the limit goes to infinity

Comment: it goes to infinity because the numerator is a constant in the limit and the denominator blows up to infinity at zero

Comment: so no directional vectors exist?

Comment: so exactly how do i check which vectors directional derivatives exist? it seems the way i did it to calculate the limit is not enough as the limit is telling me as h goes to 0, the limit does not exist.

Comment: If you choose a direction $\mathbf{y}=(0,y_2)$, you get a limit of zero because the numerator in the limit is zero.

If you choose a direction $\mathbf{y}=(y_1,0)$, you get a limit of zero.

Otherwise, the limit is infinity

Comment: got it thanks, so if i try to find directional derivatives, i have to calculate the limit then check the horizontal/vertical vectors? would that two steps be enough to cover to find all directional  derivatives?

Comment: You should check the cases $\mathbf{y} = (y_1,0), (0,y_2)$ and the cases $\mathbf{y} =  (y_1,y_2)$ with $y_1, y_2$ non zero and fixed.

Answer (score 1):

let $u=(x,y)$.

$\begin{split}f'(0,u)&=\lim\limits_{t\to0}\frac{f(0+tu)-f(0)}{t}\\
&=\lim\limits_{t\to0}\frac{\frac{t^2xy}{t^2x^2+t^2y^2}-0}{t}\\
&=\lim\limits_{t\to0}\frac{xy}{t(x^2+y^2)}\\
\end{split}$

This limit exists iff $x=0$ or $y=0$.

Thus directional derivative exist only along the vectors $0\pmb i+\pmb j$, $\pmb i+0\pmb j$.

And $f'(0,0\pmb i+\pmb j)=f'(0,\pmb i+0\pmb j)=0$.

For discontinuity at $(0,0)$, let $x_n=(0,\frac{1}{n})$ and $y_n=(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$. Then $x_n, y_n \to (0,0)$ as $n \to \infty$.

But $f(x_n)=0$ for all $n$ and $f(y_n)=\frac{1/n^2}{1/n^2+1/n^2}=\frac{1}{2}$ for all $n$.

thus, $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}f(x_n)\neq \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}f(y_n)$. There for $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$, hense not differentiable at $(0,0)$.